# Multiple values for cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm new to this and I'm trying to figure it out what is the best way of setting multiple values for a cookie/cookies. I need to store around 10 parameters(different) values(for different scenarios) in a cookies, but I have a serious doubt about this, because as far as I know cookie accept only one parameter value and therefor I will need around 10 cookies! I think it's too much, I never seen anything like this for other websites.

I'm setting the cookie like that when it's needed:

```
document.cookie = 'yesno=yes; path=/';
```

Would be nice to hear how is it needed to be done

Answer (score 0):

```
    var  common={
setCookie:function (cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
},
getCookie:function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}};common.setCookie('tz',tz,30);
```

Comment: How do I use this?

Comment: common.setCookie('yesno',yes',30);  this is function to set cookie

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to be a cookie, and you simply want to save value on the visitors browser between requests, then you can use `localStorage`. It's far simpler than trying set and parse the cookie string format.

Docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('yesno', 'yes');
localStorage.getItem('yesno'); //=> 'yes'
```

The main difference between this and cookies is that cookies get sent to the server along with every request, where local storage does not.